# Excel IF Formula with different result if blank or non blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

```
Column B - Date of Birth
Column P - Date AR Completed
Column Q - AR Due Date
```

For the cells in Column P - The AR Due date is 15 years from the date of birth (the cells from Column B).  I was using this formula for cell Q3-

```
=DATE(YEAR(B3)+15,MONTH(B3),DAY(B3))
```

When the AR is completed, the date is entered into the cell column P.

What I would like to know if it is possible, to create a formula in Q3 that will look at cell P3 and if that cell is blank, then it would calculate the 15 years from the date of birth formula

```
=DATE(YEAR(B3)+15,MONTH(B3),DAY(B3))
```

but if cell P3 has a date, then it would Q3 would display "N/A".

Comment: `=IF(P3=<>,YourFormula,"")`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, I received an error message, stating that there was something wrong with the formula.

Comment: oops: `=IF(P3="",YourFormula,"")`